# Loopback adapter still listen on 10.10.10.10 after uninstall

Tags: windows, loopback, loopback-address

I've installed on a Windows 2008 Server a loopback adapter with static IP 10.10.10.10 and subnet mask 255.255.255.0.

Having no more use for the interface I disabled and uninstalled it, but I can still ping the IP 10.10.10.10 from inside the server.

I would like to know if it's a known behaviour and if this could create some headaches in the future in terms of server management.